# Spring rest controller @ExceptionHandler return xml content and json errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-restcontroller

So I have a @RestController and I want to return and validate XML based on a schema for a front-end application in order to display them in an editor. I want the errors to be in json format in order to handle and display them with js.

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<String> throwException(
        @RequestParam(value = "flag", defaultValue = "false") Boolean flag
    ) throws Exception {
        if (flag) {
            throw new Exception();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("<xml>hello</xml>");
        }
    }


    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    ServerError exceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception ex) {
        return new ServerError(req.getRequestURL().toString(),ex);
    }

}
```

The ServerError I want to return in JSON format :

```java
public class ServerError {

    public final String url;
    public final String error;

    public ServerError(String url, Exception ex) {
        this.url = url;
        this.error = ex.getMessage();
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

So the `<xml>hello</xml>` is returned just fine but when I set the flag to `true` I get

```java
ERROR   2017-10-18 12:56:53,189 [http-nio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-2] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver  - Failed to invoke @ExceptionHandler method: eu.openminted.registry.core.exception.ServerError eu.openminted.registry.service.UserController.malformedExeption(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
```

Also, setting the `produces` to both XML and JSON yields the same result

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to solve this by removing the `produces` from `@RequestMapping` and specifying with `ResponseEntity` the type I want to return

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> throwException(
    @RequestParam(value = "flag", defaultValue = "false") Boolean flag
) throws Exception {
    if (flag) {
        throw new Exception();
    } else {
        ResponseEntity response = ResponseEntity.ok().
            contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
            body("<xml>hello</xml>");
        return response;
    }
}
```

The problem with that solution is that all of the methods have an `@annotation` with the type they produce and this doesn't, breaking uniformity.

Comment: Since you solved the issue, you should accept your own answer so people that will see your question know it's solved and therefore could be helpful.

Comment: @araknoid there is a 2 day waiting period before I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add below dependency in your pom.xml and it will work with your code with produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I didn't (de)serialize any XML in this minimal example, why would this help?

Comment: You did try to serialize by converting ServerError object to XML, so above dependency will take care of serializing this object when sending it as XML

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add content type to ResponseEntity explicitly in ExceptionHandler.

**Controller**:

```
@GetMapping("/path", produces = [MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE])
```

**ControllerAdvice**:

```
@ExceptionHandler(org.springframework.validation.BindException::class)
    fun handleBindException(
        e: org.springframework.validation.BindException
    ): ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> {    
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .body(ErrorResponse(e.message))
    }
```

**ErrorResponse**

```
data class ErrorResponse(val message: String?)
```

Tested on Spring Boot 2.1.3.RELEASE with Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

In order to make ExceptionHandler return XML format(by default it returns JSON format), there two steps need to do:

1. import the maven dependency:

> ```
>  <dependency>
>      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
>      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
>  </dependency>
> ```

2. use ResposneEntity's static method `internalServerError()`:
   `ResponseEntity.internalServerError().header("MyHeader","MyValue").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(ex);`

inside the contentType, specify `MediaType.APPLICATION_XML`.